# ENVI Example Based FX segment selection slow

Tags: envi

I am using the Example Based FX workflow in ENVI 5.5 and the segment selection tool is extremely slow. It used to be fairly fast but now takes a long time (30 seconds or more) to process one small segment even one as small as a 10m pixel.
Does anyone know of a setting to speed this up or any tips for correcting this slow behavior?